# why is buying trading-stock from cash not regarded as an expense?

Tags: stocks, bank-account

First of all I understand that bank money is an asset and so is trading-stock, but why is buying trading-stock not regarded as an expense to the business?

Answer (score 5):

Because the stock still has the same value as the money paid for it - you are just exchanging one asset for another (of course the stock value starts to change immediately, but for the accounting the fictional value is the buying price).

For the accounting, it is similar to changing a 100$ bill in five 20$ bills - same value, still assets.

Comment: Sorry stocks can gain or lose price. So the example is incorrect of converting 100 into 20 bills.

Comment: @Dheer , see the last sentence: _for the accounting the fictional value is the buying price_ - accounting considers the stock with constant value, until you realize the gain/loss when you sell it. For the accounting view, the example fits; in real life of course not.